# Median of a big dataset, possible to aggregate before?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a huge data set in redshift and have to build a Tableau report on it.
One calculation is a median of one column. Also there are several possible filters, which would change the results.

I thought about calculation the median of subsets and then the median of the medians but I am not sure how accurate that would be.

While Tableau is capable of calculating the median, it takes ages to refresh the data extract (~200kk rows) and using Live connection doesn't work because Tableau is requesting an extract for median calculations.

The data can get aggregated to 2kk rows on other columns.

I am just curious if there is a way to improve the speed or a approximation without loosing too much accuracy.

Comment: I struggle to understand the difference between "approximate median" and "average".  Usually, medians want to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the median should not be excessively expensive.  Are you using the built-in function?

```
select median(value)
from t;
```

I would expect this to be a little slower than a simpler aggregation (such as `count()` or `average()`).  But it should be acceptable.

You can then add additional filters as you wish.

Comment: No, because I wasn't sure how I get all results depending on the possible filters in Tableau.

I try to specify the filter issue. I have these coloumns:
Date - Country - City - Gender - CustomerID - Price
Nothing is unique. (Same customer can order multiple times.

In the end Tableau has to be able to calculate the median for all possible combinations. For example 2 out of 6 countries, all cities, one specific month.

Comment: @Tonne . . . Those are `where` conditions.  You can still use `median()`.